# Duplicate collection from single server to cluster

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to duplicate collection from single server to cluster? I have a collection on test server (single machine) and I will copy the collection to another server (cluster) and I'm not sure if I can use duplicate collection.

I want to copy collection once.

Comment: Do you just want to copy it once, or do you want the collection to be synchronized in real-time between the single server and the cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use [mongoexport](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/) on the source server to export the collection to a file.

```
mongoexport --db yourDB --collection yourCollection --out yourCollection.json
```

When the collection doesn't already exist on the destination shard or isn't yet configured to be sharded, you should do so now by connecting to the mongos instance with the mongo shell and using the command:

```
sh.shardCollection( "yourDatabase.yourCollection", { yourDesiredShardKey: 1 } )
```

Then use [mongoimport](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) on the destination to import the collection.

```
mongoimport --db yourDB --collection yourCollection --file yourCollection.json
```

Both `mongoimport` and `mongoexport` have optional `--host` and `--port` parameters to import from / export to a remote server. But I would recommend you to copy the file to the destination server yourself. First, this should be faster. Second, in a securely configured network, you shouldn't be able to access both test and production database from the same machine anyway, at least not without authentication.

Comment: I prefer mongodump and mongorestore, this will export the data in bson format. Data types of numeric values are not preserved when exporting as json. This would cause number format exceptions in destination app.

Answer (score 0):

For a collection to use a cluster's power, you need to have shard options. Duplicating the test collection won't do that.

You can create a new collection with the right sharding options and then copy items of the test collection into it

`db.test.mycollection.find().forEach( function(x){db.otherdb.othercollection.insert(x)} );`